# JPGraph Lineplot SetFillColor Upwards

Tags: php, fill, jpgraph, line-plot

Is there any way to set a LinePlot->SetFillColor to go upwards instead of going down in JPGraph - PHP?

[image]

```
  $p6 = new LinePlot($arrayLimSpecI);
  $graph->Add($p6);
  $p6->SetColor("#0B610B");
  $p6->SetWeight(3);
  $p6->SetStyle("solid");
  //FillColor Fills the plotline from point 0 to point X
  $p6->SetFillColor('red@0.65');
```

What I've tried:

```
       $band = new PlotBand(HORIZONTAL,BAND_SOLID,$valueS,"max",'red');
        $band->ShowFrame(false);
        $graph->AddBand($band);
```

But this band doesn't seem to adjust to the dynamic marks that the graphic has got. If I set valueS to show on Y-Mark 10 it will show instead on the mark point 40.

**EDIT:** Another library that is currently supported or is capable or doing this is welcomed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support for a third party script

Comment: How so? Is it because of the php-lib? Or should I add code to clearify?

Comment: I am not, I am trying to find an alternative to Plotline->SetFillColor (the php method) on this lib (which, if you know it would be useful), there are other questions like this on Stackoverflow just not adressing this issue. It has never caused an outrage such as yours.

Comment: no outrage, it simple is offtopic as currently written.